# JS make all values in array different

Tags: javascript

This is a much simplified version of my real problem so ideally I'm looking a simple solution without builtin functions.

I have an array:

```
let data = [5,5,5,5,5];
```

I want to start at the second item and compare it to the first. If they are the same I want to increase by one so my array looks like this:

```
let data = [5,6,5,5,5];
```

I then want to compare the next array item to all the other ones I've checked and increase by 1 if there are any the same so the array would look like this:

```
let data = [5,6,6,5,5];
```

but now there are two values the same in the values I've checked, so I want to check for similar values in the array I've already checked and add one to the item at the current array index if the current value is the same as any that have come before. 6 has been used, so I want to change the array to look like this:

```
let data = [5,6,7,5,5];
```

And so on...

I've got this, but it's not producing the result I want:

```
let data = [5,5,5,5,5]
const looper = () => {
  for (let i=-1; i<data.length; i++) {
    console.log("i", i)
    for (let j=1; j<data.length; j++) {
      console.log("j", j)
      if (data[i] <= data[i-1] ) {
        console.log("DATA", i, data[i])
        data[i] += i
        console.log("DATA", i, data)
        looper()
      } else {
        continue
      }
    }             
  }
}

looper()
```

Comment: Would `[5, 5, 4, 5, 5]` turn into `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` or would it be `[5, 6, 5, 7, 8]`?

Comment: do you have some more examples and results?

Comment: Since it is a recursive function you do not need the second for loop.

Comment: So what is the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an object and take the reference to the largest value.

```js
function fn(array) {
    const 
        getValue = v => {
            if (v in values) return getValue(values[v]);
            values[v] = v + 1;
            return v;
        },
        values = {};
    return array.map(getValue)
}

console.log(...fn([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]));
console.log(...fn([5, 5, 4, 5, 5]));
console.log(...fn([5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 4]));
```

Funky other data set.

```js
function fn(array) {
    const
        getValue = (values = {}) => v => {
            if (v in values) return getValue(values)(values[v]);
            values[v] = v + 1;
            return v;
        };

    return Object
        .entries(array.reduce((r, o) => {
            Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => (r[k] ??= []).push(v));
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .map(([k, v]) =>[k, v.map(getValue())])
        .reduce((r, [k, a]) => a.map((v, i) => ({ ...r[i], [k]: v })), []);
}

const
    data = [{ cx: 2, cy: 3 }, { cx: 2, cy: 3 }, { cx: 2, cy: 3 }, { cx: 2, cy: 3 }, { cx: 2, cy: 3 }],
    result = fn(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A slightly better approach by using only a single loop of the data and keeping the values along with the key.

```js
const
    getValue = (values = {}) => {
        const
            fn = (k, v) => {
                const key = [k, v].join('|');
                if (key in values) return fn(k, values[key]);
                values[key] = v + 1;
                return v;
            };
        return fn;
    },
    data = [{ cx: 2, cy: 3 }, { cx: 2, cy: 3 }, { cx: 2, cy: 3 }, { cx: 2, cy: 3 }, { cx: 2, cy: 3 }],
    getFn = getValue(),
    result = data.map(o => Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(o)
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, getFn(k, v)])
    ));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: "_... without builtin functions._". Better remove `.map`

Comment: @DevCl9, it is easy to replace a map with a for loop.

Comment: I know. I was just being technical :)

Comment: I've had a go with this and the 'in' doesn't help me either. Sorry to be picky, but I'm having trouble generalising this so I can pass in an array [{cx: 2, cy: 3}, {cx: 2, cy: 3}, {cx: 2, cy: 3}, {cx: 2, cy: 3}, {cx: 2, cy: 3},]

Comment: @Davtho1983, what is the expected result of it?

Comment: [{cx: 2, cy: 3}, {cx: 3, cy: 4}, {cx: 4, cy: 5}, {cx: 5, cy: 6}, {cx: 6, cy: 7}]

Comment: I'm trying to do something a little more complicated with an array of objects {cx, cy, rad} that checks if any of them overlap another

Comment: That's awesome! :D

Answer (score 1):

Break this down into two parts:

Part 1:

Adjust all elements in array 2 based on array 1

Part 2:

Make numbers in array 2 unique: Here you need to iterate over your array continually, until no changes are found in an iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const fun = ra => {
  for (let i = 1; i < ra.length; i++) {
    let k = 0;
    while (k < i) 
    ra[i] === ra[k] ? (ra[i]++, k = 0) : k++;
  }
  return ra;
}
console.log(...fun([3, 3, 3]));
console.log(...fun([4, 3, 3]));
console.log(...fun([4, 3, 3, 5]));
```